# How to pass input for a post to mongo using clicked and expressjs

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, post, click

I have the following model for mongoose that I want to use in my database, I want to know how to take input from a bootstrap page as post it to mongo.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var muv = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    empId: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    num: {type: String, required: true},
    job: {type: String, required: true},
    store: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Stores'},
});

schema.plugin(muv);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', schema);
```

I tried referencing elements from the html template used in the component that will use a service to interact with expressjs but It wouldn't work.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from "./message.model";
import { MessageService } from "./message.service";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'deta',
  templateUrl: 'details.component.html',
  providers: [MessageService]
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
   messages: Message[] = [];

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.messageService.getMessages()
            .subscribe(
                messages => this.messages = messages,
                error => console.error(error)
            );
    }

    onAddMessage() {
        const message = new Message(' It still worked!');
        this.messages.push(message);
        this.messageService.saveMessage(message)
            .subscribe(
                () => console.log('Success!'),
                error => console.error(error)
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using ngModel as

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputMessage" />
```

Method should be as

```
onAddMessage() {

        this.messages.push(this.inputMessage);
        this.messageService.saveMessage(this.messages)
            .subscribe(
                () => console.log('Success!'),
                error => console.error(error)
            );
    }
```

Declare the variable as

```
inputMessage:string=''
```

Comment: But how do I do this having multiple input boxes for details and then a submit button to post the contents of the input box?  there about 5 strings in my model I want to use, do I have to make a service for each string?

Comment: Its your call. if you feel that five separate calls will be rapid ho with that else wait and combine all 5 and raise a single call.

Comment: Ok thanks, one last questions, if im adding an employee through one call and the constructor of the model takes all the elements listed above that are entered by the user, do i let them enter the store and it will automatically look in that store for a store name that matches and if there is one it will reference it and if not it wall just throw an error or be set to null?

Comment: Once you are subscribed to the store, the changes in corresponding store automatically notifies the subscribed objects. So, if you are creating a new item, push it to service and dispatch data to the store, which updates as required